# xd-singlenode command gives Error:

Tags: groovy, spring-xd

The instruction on http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/ is to enter `xd-singlenode` at the command prompt but this command generates 
"Error: Could not find or load main class Files\spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE\xd.config...xd-singlenode-logback.groovy"

However, this file does exists in the config directory. 
Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the actual command your running, and the actual stacktrace?

Comment: Did you install under `Program Files`? Java generally doesn't like spaces in directory names.

Comment: The actual command is xd-singlenode, and Error: Could not find or load main class Files\spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE\xd.config...xd-singlenode-logback.groovy is the actual trace.                                                                                                              Program Files is the window's default place where all applications including java is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this kind of issue some time back when I directly execute xd-singlenode in RHEL.
   Can you go one folder back and try bin/xd-singlenode ?

Thanks
S.Satish

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Windows OS)

Try placing "spring-xd-#.#.#.Release" folder in C:\Users\your_username\SpringXD\

Make sure there's no spaces as Gary Russell has mentioned.

Set following environment variables:

XD_HOME = C:\Users\your_username\SpringXD\spring-xd-#.#.#.RELEASE\xd

XD_SHELL = C:\Users\your_username\SpringXD\spring-xd-#.#.#.RELEASE\shell

**Append** the path environment variable to include (do not delete existing path):

%XD_HOME%\bin

%XD_SHELL%\bin

To test - start a new windows terminal and run:

xd-singlenode

xd-shell

Answer (score 0):

I think you're problem should be resoloved by running xd-singlenode as sudo.  So cd into $XD_HOME/bin and then run

```
sudo ./xd-singlenode
```